# Visual Studio 2015 Builds on Run Test 100% of the Time

Tags: visual-studio, build, mstest

Every time I run unit tests, Visual Studio deems it necessary to build the entire solution every time. I've recently discovered that not everyone on my team has this happen to them but they can't tell me *why* they aren't building every time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can tune your VS settings here:

Open the Tools -> Options... menu item, expand the Projects and Solutions node, click on Build and Run, and in the On Run, ... dropdown, select Never Build.